# Undefined Arrow in Button OnclickListener - Android Studio

Tags: android, button, listener

When I watch a tutorial on internet, I realized that there is a define arrow in onclick listener function as shown below. I couldn't understand what does it mean and how I can add it to my code. Could you please explain what this arrow mean? Thanks.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJuLi.png)

Comment: this hidden arrow show a code when you click on it. it is onClickListner. search for it

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

The arraw is called "Lambda Expression".

[More info on Lambda Expression Can Be Found Here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/lambda-expressions.html)

Of course, the major Java 8 buzz is around lambdas (also called closures), and that’s where this two-part series will focus. But a language feature, on its own, will often appear anything but useful or interesting unless there’s a certain amount of support behind it. Several features in Java 7 fit that description: enhanced numeric literals, for example, really couldn’t get most people’s eyes to light up.

Hope it will make you understand.